# Is it better practice to retain an extra reference to a subclass or cast to a subclass to call methods specific to that subclass?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a system where an object can take a generic configuration object (think flyweight pattern).  I also have a subclass which takes a subclassed configuration object.

In order to access properties that are specific to the subclass configuration object, is it better to maintain a second reference to the subclass or cast to the subclass?

e.g.

```
class Base {
    public BaseConf Conf;
    public Base(BaseConf C) {
        Conf = C;
    }
}

class Derived : Base {
    public DerivedConf DerConf;  //Create an extra reference, no casting
    public Derived(DerivedConf DC) : base(DC) {
        DerConf = DC;
    }

    public void PrintName() {
        Console.WriteLine(DerConf.Name);
    }
}

class BaseConf {
    public BaseConf() {}
}

class DerivedConf : BaseConf {
    public string Name;
    public DerivedConf(string n) : base() {
        Name = n;
    }
}
```

vs.

```
class Base {
    public BaseConf Conf;
    public Base(BaseConf C) {
        Conf = C;
    }
}

class Derived : Base {
    public Derived(DerivedConf DC) : base(DC) {}

    public void PrintName() {
        DerivedConf DerConf = Conf as DerivedConf; //Cast, no extra reference
        Console.WriteLine(DerConf.Name);
    }
}

class BaseConf {
    public BaseConf() {}
}

class DerivedConf : BaseConf {
    public string Name;
    public DerivedConf(string n) : base() {
        Name = n;
    }
}
```

Both have an identical output

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you use a system like this. But one alternative would be to make the `Conf` members properties instead of fields, and implement the derived one using the base class one as if it was a backing field: `DerivedConf DerConf { get { return (DerivedConf) base.Conf; } set { base.Conf = value; } }`

Comment: FYI you've received the downvotes because its a bit opinion based.  Both are entirely valid.

Comment: @Flydog57 I've created such a system as this.  I had a bunch of physical devices which had configurations.  The heirarchy of devices mapped to the heirarchy of configurations.  The base configuration had things such as  DeviceID and Address which all devices had.  it worked well. The answer below from CheifTwoPencils is the best option

Comment: @TimRutter I figured that would be the case but I was curious enough about what others thought that I'll happily take the downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't want to do either of those and you can get around both by making the `Base` take a generic, like so:

```
class Base<T> where T : BaseConf
{
    public T Conf;
    public Base(T C)
    {
        Conf = C;
    }
}

class Derived : Base<DerivedConf>
{
    public Derived(DerivedConf DC) : base(DC)
    { 
    }

    public void PrintName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Conf.Name);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var derived = new Derived(new DerivedConf("Foo"));
    derived.PrintName(); // Foo
}
```

Comment: Both seemed a bit hacky, glad to know there's a better alternative.